# Creating nested components from json in angular 2 programatically

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular-components

I am creating a dropdown which can have any no of levels from a json like

```
    [
        {name:'Hi',value:[]},
        {name:'Hello',value:[
            {name:'Xoxo',value:[]},
            {name:'Yolo',value:[]}
        ]},
        {name:'Hey',value:[]},
        {name:'Hola',value:[]}
    ]
```

The value can contain another json object. Now I am doing this in angular 2.
What I tried was using recursion in typescript code.

```
createDropdownHtml(links,menuText){
    this.html+='<clr-dropdown>';
    this.html+=` <button type="button" clrDropdownTrigger>`+menuText+`
            </button>`;
    this.html+='<clr-dropdown-menu *clrIfOpen>';
    for(let link of links){
        if(link.value.length==0){
            console.log(link.name+' not nested');
            this.html+='<button type="button" clrDropdownItem (click)="linkClicked($event)">'+link.name+'</button>'
        }
        else{
            console.log(link.name+' nested');
            this.createDropdownHtml(link.value,link.name);
        }
    }
    this.html+=`</clr-dropdown-menu>
    </clr-dropdown>`;
}
```

Now in @Component template I wrote `{{html}}` but this just printed the html as a string.

Then I tried using `<div [innerHTML]="html"></div>` but then the angular components were not rendered.

My problem is fairly simple. I want to create an angular dropdown menu with any number of nested dropdowns using only a json file. Since I cannot do recursion in html it is really no clicking how will I do this.

Comment: you can try with structural directive ng-for loop in angular

Comment: The thing with *ngFor is it cannot generate the component again like recursion.

Comment: Ok i understand then you have to go with creating dynamic components

Comment: I have created a sample template creation using ng-template please check it and reply

Answer (score 0):

In your case we want to create **ng-template** and add it pro grammatically using **viewContainerRef**. I will provide an sample code based on your json array structure

**Html**

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <ng-template #dropdownvalue>
    </ng-template>
  </ul>
</div>

<ng-template #dropdown let-data>
  <li><a (click)="call(data.link)">{{data.link}}</a></li>
</ng-template>
```

the html included dropdown is bootstrap

**Ts**

```
@ViewChild('dropdownvalue',{read:ViewContainerRef}) dropdownvalue : ViewContainerRef
  @ViewChild('dropdown') dropdown;

  data = [
        {name:'Hi',value:[]},
        {name:'Hello',value:[
            {name:'Xoxo',value:[{name:'Hey',value:[{name:'Hola',value:[]}]}]},
            {name:'Yolo',value:[]}
        ]},
        {name:'Hey',value:[]},
        {name:'Hola',value:[]}
    ]

    ngAfterViewInit(){
      this.data.forEach((value,index)=>{
        this.dropdownvalue.createEmbeddedView(this.dropdown,{$implicit:{link:value.name}})
        if(value.value.length > 0){
          this.change(this.data[index])
        }
      })
    }

    change(data){
      data.value.forEach((value,index)=>{
        this.dropdownvalue.createEmbeddedView(this.dropdown,{$implicit:{link:value.name}})
        if(value.value.length > 0){
          this.change(data.value[index])
        }
      })
    }
```

For better clarification refer demo [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tthgr4?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: I wanted something like nested dropdown like if I click Hello then its nested values come in another dropdown.